# UIAlertView to delete a row from UITableView Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uialertview

everyone. I'm currently trying to figure out how I would add a UIAlertView that would ask the user if they want to delete all of the items or just one from a shopping list.

I'm having some trouble figuring this out since from all that I've found I have to use didDismissButtonWithIndex to figure out which button was tapped.

Any ideas?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        for (myData *item in self.itemData)
        {
            if(item.count > 1)
            {
                UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"delete how many?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"1" otherButtonTitles:@"All", nil];
                [alert show];
            }
            else
            {
                int index = indexPath.row;
                [self.itemData removeObjectAtIndex:index];

                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

            }
        }
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex == 0) {
        //selected item's count--
    }
    if(buttonIndex == 1) {
        //selected item deleted completely
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is your issue? using `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` is a perfectly fine approach :) if you want to be a bit clearer on what the indexes mean you can declare them as constants to give them some additional semantics

Comment: r u need the alert method in didselectatrowatindexpath or any button action method

Comment: @nburk I know that didDismissWithButtonIndex: is the correct way of going about this. I'm just not exactly sure I will delete the item from there without tableView commiEditingStyle.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS8 you can use UIAlertController

```
UIAlertController *myAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"How many?"
                                                                  message:@""
                                                           preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
```

And define actions directly in UIAlertAction block

```
UIAlertAction *oneAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"One"
                                                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                       handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                          //define action
}];

UIAlertAction *allAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"All"
                                                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                       handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                          //define action
}];
```

Then you would just add these actions to myAlert and display it.

```
[myAlert addAction:oneAction];
[myAlert addAction:allAction];

[self presentViewController:myAlert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: This would be nice, but unfortunately I am not using IOS8